# What symbol to choose to indicate a subcategory or next page

Tags: typography, icon, typesetting, symbols, character

In a very short descriptive text I want to indicate **that a user has to open several cascading/nested sections in a menu structure**. At the moment I use the <kbd>></kbd> character to indicate the structure. But is there a better looking character/icon/symbol available?

I only have the default typeset for an iOS device available:

[image: subcategory typography icon or symbol]

Comment: I think `>` is a good "step" symbol. so `one>two>three`

Comment: I use `>` or `->`, in some quick googling I also see people using `→`

Comment: Dashes "/" are often used for this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is subtle but it's better to use the right chevron arrow, `&rsaquo;` when written in HTML, instead of the greater than symbol for denoting submenus and the like. It's also more compact than an arrow symbol.

`Settings > Twitter`

Vs.

`Settings › Twitter`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the ">" symbol looks subtle and not recognised as it was planned to be.

Probably, to make it more prominent you can make it bold: <kbd>File **>** New</kbd>

Secondly, the "classic symbol" for submenus is triangle -<kbd>File ▶︎ New</kbd> <kbd>File ➤ New</kbd>

Next, you can use arrows and a hand: <kbd>File ☞ New</kbd> <kbd>File ☛ New</kbd> <kbd>File ⍈ New</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To indicate a subcategory or next page, I'd recommend following the conventions used in the manual of the OS or device instead of looking for a symbol that looks pretty. Hopefully, the writers of the manual have already thought of accessibility as well; e.g. will the character make sense when uttered by screen readers?

For example, the [iPad User Guide for iOS 8.4 Software](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1725/en_US/ipad_user_guide.pdf) uses the *greater-than sign* (U+003E) when indicating a sequence of menu entries to follow:

"**Set the auto-lock time**. Go to Settings > General > Auto-Lock."

And the slash is used to indicate switches: "turn on Lock/Unlock".